# Loading configuration and route.rb twice and produces error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

**Rails.application.initialize!** command in environment.rb loads the files including route.rb twice when executing test using rspec. It works when executing it in production environment and route file is loaded exactly once. What may be the issue. I am using gemset

```
group :development,:test do
  gem "rails-erd"
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

Comment: Initialization are loaded twice in rsepc testing environment. While running it in development environment it is working fine

Comment: while calling Rails.application.initialize! . Except test.rb, all other files are invoked twice(including routes.rb).